# $model->save() doesn't use entity

Tags: model, entities, codeigniter-4

I am slowly learning version 4 of CodeIgniter and I stumble upon a strange behaviour:

When using the `save()` method of my model, it only saves the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps.

Here is the useful code.

## Migration

```
public function up()
{
    $this->forge->addField('id');
    $this->forge->addField([
        'title' => [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 127
        ],
        'content' => [
            'type' => 'text'
        ],
        'slug' => [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'constraint' => 127
        ],
        'created_at' => [
            'type' => 'datetime'
        ],
        'updated_at' => [
            'type' => 'datetime'
        ],
        'deleted_at' => [
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'null' => true
        ]
    ]);
    $this->forge->createTable('articles');
}
```

**NOTE:** it works fine, the table is correctly created in the database, as you can see below.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(9)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(127) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug       | varchar(127) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

## Entity

```
namespace App\Entities;

class Article
{
}
```

## Model

```
namespace App\Models;

class ArticleModel extends \CodeIgniter\Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $returnType = 'App\Entities\Article';
    protected $allowedFields = ['title', 'content', 'slug'];
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
}
```

## Calling the model

I tried calling the model from two different places: a seeder and a controller, using the code below.

```
$article = new \App\Entities\Article();
$article->title = 'Article Title';
$article->content = 'Article Content';

$model = new \App\Models\ArticleModel();
$model->save($article);
echo $model->getLastQuery();
```

Both times, the result was the same. The `echo` shows the following.

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2019-10-09 02:25:56', '2019-10-09 02:25:56')
```

I have no idea how to tell my model (I think it's the responsible for the bad behaviour) to take into account its `$allowedFields` to save the article.

Can you see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `save()` method of the model only accepts objects of the class `CodeIgniter\Entitiy` in that case.

The good thing to do is to make `Article` extend that class:

```
namespace App\Entities;

class Article extends \CodeIgniter\Entitiy
{
}
```

This solves the problem.